# generate pwa to apk or ios with angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, angular8

I have created a `PWA` app with Angular 8.

Now I need to build the apk file to android or build to ios phone for installing it on the cell phone.

I have two question.

**A )** Can I build the apk file for android or ios ?

If yes **then HOW ?**

**B )** If **No** then how can I build apk for android in Angular 8 ????

I publish the site on the iis and pass it in this website : [Generator Site](https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/) but it not gived to me any thing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like cordova or capacitor. These basically provide you with basic ios/android base apps with a webview, where your App will be displayed in. Also, they provide a plugin layer for native functionality. Refer to the official documentations to get started.

Comment: You can also make the Angular App to PWA and with help of TWS (Trusted Web Service), you can generate apk easily.